# Canon MP280 All in One prints but scanner not recognized

Tags: printing, canon, scanner

I recently installed 12.04 LTS after not using any Linux distro for several years. My Canon MP280 worked perfectly as far as printing goes and I was even able to set it up on a Samba share and print from a Windows 7 machine.

However, when I open Simple Scan it does not detect a scanner. I did find some instructions online but the scanner is still not recognized in Simple Scan even after installing a couple .deb packages from the Canon site.

I also couldn't seem to find the ScanGear package after installing those .deb packages as well but I haven't had a chance to delve fully into it.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my own problem. I went to the Canon printer driver daily site at

- http://www.launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-trunk

and then added the PPA to my sources using the instructions there:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
```

I then updated my lists via `sudo apt-get update`. The OS then prompted me to install 4 new packages which I did and everything seems to be working now!

Answer (score 1):

Scanner will work for me, but only if I run 'scangearmp' from terminal as root.