# Scanner not working

Tags: canon, scanner

I have a canon MP-280 series printer cum scanner. I can use the printer, but when I try to use Simple Scan its saying **no scanner connected**. Please help me fix this.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/182604/canon-mp280-all-in-one-prints-but-scanner-not-recognized

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the driver is available for download as a .deb

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1582497